# reading asp.net sitemap

Tags: sitemap

I'm thinking of using sitemap in my asp.net application. Will sitemap affect the application's performance in any way, I mean will it be read repeatedly or only once like web.config and stored in memory?

Answer (score 0):

only once read sitemap 
later  cache

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are going to use an **XML site-map** it will be read once. Usage of XML sitemap is one of the best-practices to adopt.

For more info on implementing it, check the [MS recommendation for XML sitemaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478951.aspx)